# Variable not defined it says want is not defined when it is?

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mmg2220/Documents/gilliam.a2.v3.py", line 9, in <module>
    if want==1:
NameError: name 'want' is not defined
```

```
important = int(input("is it important? 1= yes, 2 = no")) 
if important == 1:
    Urgent= int(input("Is it Urgent? 1= yes, 2 = no")) #start of urgent
if Urgent == 1:#start of bestime 
    besttime= int(input("is it the best use of my time to do this myself? 1=yes, 2 = no"))

if important==2: #end of important
    want= int(input("Is it a want? 1= yes, 2 = no")) #start of want   
if want==1:
    print("@Someday/Maybe")

if want == 2:
    print ("trash") #end of want 

if Urgent== 2:
    action=int(input("Is it actionable? 1=yes, 2 = no")) #end of urgent start of action
if bestime== 1:
    minutes= int(input("Will it take more than 15 minutes? 1=yes, 2 = no"))#start of minutes

if besttime== 2:#end of besttime 
    print ("Delegate it")
    print ("Waitingfor")

if action== 1:
    besttime= int(input("is it the best use of my time to do this myself? 1=yes, 2 = no"))
if action== 2:
    reference = int(input("Ia it reference Material? 1=yes, 2=no"))
if reference== 1:
    print ("@file")
if reference== 2:
    print ("Trash")
```

Comment: can you fix format, use code tags around code

Comment: As a side note, code using random spacing, random capitalization, etc. is very hard to read. Pick a standard and stick with it. If you don't have any reason to use any particular standard, use the one defined in [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Also, you should learn about `elif` and `else`. If `important==1` is true, it's pointless to check `important==2`. And if neither one is true, you probably want to at least print some kind of warning to the user complaining about their invalid input. So, you can use `if important==1:`, then `elif important==2:`, then `else:` to handle those three cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want to do the `want` test only if `important==2`.

In Python, indentation determines control. Code that's more indented than a preceding `if` statement only runs if that `if` statement's condition is true. Code that's dedented back to the same level as the `if` statement runs *always*.

In your case, `want` is only defined if `important==2`, and your `want`-based code only makes sense if `important==2`, but you're running it unconditionally, so in every other case, you get a `NameError`.

the fix is simple: indent the code so that it's part of the `if` that's supposed to control it:

```
if important==2: #end of important
    want= int(input("Is it a want? 1= yes, 2 = no")) #start of want   
    if want==1:
        print("@Someday/Maybe")
    if want == 2:
        print ("trash") #end of want
```

You have the same problem many other times in your code. For example,  you do the `if Urgent==1:` always, instead of as part of the `if important==1:`. Obviously, you need to fix all of these, not just one, to make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

`want` is only defined if `important == 2` as per these lines:

```
if important==2: #end of important
    want= int(input("Is it a want? 1= yes, 2 = no")) #start of want
```

As a workaround, you could always define want at the beginning of your script with a dummy number, something like `want=0` as the first line. Any time you call a conditional with a variable you will get an error if the variable has not been initialized in some way.